# Listview not showing

Tags: java, android, listview, display

I have a ArrayList on integers containing unique id.

I have this method to populate listview.

```
public void getDataDetails(int id)
    {
            Cursor c = db.getData(id);
            String[] from = new String[]{ID, name};
            int[] to = new int[]{R.id.layout_id, R.id.layout_name};

            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.layout, c, from, to, 0);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And in my onCreate method I have this code. Variable data is my ArrayList which has values of 1 and 2.

```
listview= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
for (int x=0; x < data.size(); x++)
{
      getDataDetails(data.get(x));
}
```

My problem is the only data that is showing is the data when x=2. There should be two listview containing data in x=1 and x=2. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in `onCreate()`

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.layout, c, from, to, 0);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: What difference would it be if I write it in function inside my activity and then call that function in my onCreate?

Comment: you are creating adapter and attaching it to listview in every iteration of for loop which is not feasible. Get all data in arraylist and then populate listview with it.

Comment: In the first iteration listview is populate but when second iteration performs it overlaps the first one that is why it is showing data when x =2

Comment: I understand. Thanks

Comment: glad it helped and you can upvote and correct green my answer if you don't mind :)

Comment: Please don't just drop code into an answer but give a couple of sentences of background.

Comment: Right but I have given explanation in above comments

Comment: @HunterWinchester did you upvoted my answer or someone else?

Comment: @HunterWinchester Tnanks and if my answer has solved your problem then you can mark correct green mark to answer so that other user can have idea about proper solution as well..:)